# Sort Objects By datetime in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting, timestamp, datetime-format

I have contacts that have SMS messages associated with them. Each sms record has properties such as `time`. Time is an timestamp string formatted as this example

```
2022-04-29T16:10:43-06:00
```

I am trying to sort this array of sms messages so that the latest one is the last one and the earliest one is the first one in the array. I thought I had it nailed down but apparently I don't. Its still not perfectly sorting at all.

```js
this.getRecent()
    .then(contacts => {
        const sorted = contacts.map(contact => {
            contact.sms = contact.sms.sort((a,b) => (a.time.localeCompare(b.time));
            return contact;
        });
        // rest of code here
    })
    .catch(err => this.handleError(err));
```

Comment: What do you mean by not sorting? What is the data you have, what sorting do you expect, and what is the actual sort order?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to sort an object array by date property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10123953)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question, I'm making the assumption that the `contact.sms` object contains an array of objects where `time` is a string (localeCompare is called). Since dates can have operators applied to them, you can sort them like any number.

```js
const dates = [
  new Date("2022-04-29T16:10:43-06:00"),
  new Date("2023-04-29T16:10:43-06:00"),
  new Date("2022-01-29T16:10:43-06:00")
]

console.log(dates)

dates.sort((a, b) => a - b)

console.log(dates)
```

In your case,

```js
// Sorts dates where the least recent is first.
contact.sms = contact.sms.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.time) - new Date(b.time));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse them to a `Date` and compare the milliseconds:

```
contact.sms.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.time) - new Date(b.time));
```

Or swap `a` and `b` if you want to reverse the order.